# Debug messages in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Flutter to programm an App.
I just wanted to get variables into my output or elsewhere,
I tried using print('message') or debugprint('message') but I didnt get any output.

Have u guys any idea how to do it?

Comment: Which IDE are you using for your development? Can you provide some code or screenshots about your tryings?

Comment: Im using Visual Studio Code

Comment: What about your environment? Is it Windows, Linux, or Mac?

Comment: Could you post some code of your print statement? Your output of print should come in the run terminal. Maybe you have put the print in a wrong postion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio Code, you can open a window from `Terminal => New Terminal`. Then, the `flutter run` command will print the desired output on that terminal.

[image]